# How to make android softkeyboard key text color bright?

Tags: android

i am working on a soft keyboard but my keyboard key label is not looking so clear.
i used android:keyTextColor="#000000" to set the color of key label text.
but i noticed that the color is not looked like on that app.
here is the pic of my keyboard key level.

[image: Keyboard]

this key level is not so black and there is some shadow on it.
but why this happened?

Comment: Try `android:keyPreviewOffset`

Comment: Finally i have found my ans and that is, set  android:shadowRadius="0.0" to your keyboard view